# INDEX and MATCH / VLOOKUP formula to look for nearest future date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to have a formula to lookup the Primary Key on the other table and return the value of date. But with a twist, the return value should be the closest future date. Is there a formula for this? Thank you.

[image: Sample Table Here]

The return value should be the closest future date in today's date instead of the first item that it will lookup.

Hoping for your kind help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$D$6:$D$25/((A6=$C$6:$C$25)*(TODAY()<$D$6:$D$25)),1)
```

[image]

Adjust your ranges as required.

Aggregate performs array like operations.  As such avoid using full column references like C:C.  Also, Today is a volatile function.  As such it will recalculate anytime something on your spreadsheet changes.  That combined with the fact that its in an array operation means you will want to limit its usage.  If you notice your worksheet bogging down with calculations, either turn automatic calculations off for the sheet, or look at changing TODAY() to a cell reference where a date is entered.

Comment: Wow! This really works. Thanks a lot! This would help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The equation `{=MIN(IF(F8:F11>NOW(),F8:F10,402132))}`, where `F8:F11` is the range of Scheduled Dates will give the minimum date after and closest to the current date.

Note: This is an array formula so you will need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then use VLookup or Index/Match as per usual.

Comment: Doesn't this give the latest date in the past rather than the earliest date in the future?

Comment: You're going to think I'm awfully nit-picking, but the other part of the question was that OP wanted to match their 'primary key' in table 1 with the one in table 2 so would need that to be in before I could upvote the answer.

Comment: @TomSharpe Not at all. I wanted to add it as a comment as it was a partial answer but figured it would be harder to read. It also looked like he knew what he was doing so I wanted to give him a step in the right direction. That said, ForwardEd's answer looks more appropriate if it works since it isn't a formula array.